# how to modify subscription page in blogengine.Net

Tags: blogengine.net

How can I modify subscription page (RSS Feed) in blogengine.Net

I want to add website header & footer in subscription page

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

RSS feed is XML document that has to comply with schema, you can't add HTML header/footer to it. Most you can do is to [specify your own CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118685/how-can-i-apply-my-css-stylesheet-to-an-rss-feed), but even that can be ignored by RSS readers.