# Add a CSS stylesheet to Wordpress RSS feeds in an upgrade friendly manner

Tags: css, wordpress, rss, wordpress-theming

How can I add a stylesheet to all of the wordpress RSS feeds? I'd prefer not to just edit the RSS templates in the wp-includes directory as these could then break in a future update. Any other ways to do it, perhaps using a child theme somehow?

Comment: Why would you want to include CSS in your RSS?

Comment: I use a gravity form at the bottom of each post for people to opt in to my mailing list. Gravity forms structures each form as an unordered list with 'list-style-type: none;' so the bullet points are not shown. In my RSS feed, the form is displayed with bullet points which looks terrible to RSS readers, and I also use Mailchimp's RSS to email feature to send blog posts to my mailing list, so it looks really bad there too.

Comment: The form shouldn't be a part of your RSS in the first place. Add the form after your post, not in it.

Answer (score 1):

CSS isn't supported in most RSS feed readers, so even if you added code to use one, unfortunately the answer is that you can't from a practical perspective. Not really Wordpress specific - see: [How can I apply my CSS stylesheet to an RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118685/how-can-i-apply-my-css-stylesheet-to-an-rss-feed).