# How make an aesthetically pleasing rss feed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rss

I was trying to find a good example of an nice looking rss feed, all the ones I've seen usually look a bit dated (like the one generated here http://feed.mikle.com/) and I was wondering if there is new breed of rss feeds out there. Something similar to the bootstrap look and feel would be perfect, thanks for any advice.

(Whenever I try to google "web design rss feeds" or something along those lines I just get a bunch of rss feeds for to follow XD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feeds are designed for feed readers to display, but it is possible to [style feeds with CSS](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/208.cfm) or [XSLT](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/improving-an-xml-feed-display-through-css-and-xslt/). See also: [How can I apply my CSS stylesheet to an RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118685/how-can-i-apply-my-css-stylesheet-to-an-rss-feed)